# How to click on a img id in HTML using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am unable to find a way to click on a button that is an  tag and not a .
Here is the tag I am trying to click on. Btw that plus.png is used multiple times in the page.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="text-center"><img src="./assets/img/plus.png" id="add_address"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this xpath to click on it.

```
//img[@id='add_address']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id='add_address']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@id='add_address']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id='add_address']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id='add_address']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Not sure if we have unique `ID`, if `ID` is unique then you should give preference to `ID` not `xpath`.